# What does it mean for a "formula to be undefined"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, indeterminate-forms

I was covering the techniques used sketch rational functions of five different types as follows:

[image]

However, then I encountered this: 
[image]

And, Ij just can't find out what it means for the formula to be undefined in this context. Can someone elaborate please, an example would be favourable.

Comment: They probably mean that the denominator has zeros, and for those $x$ where the denominator vanishes, the formula becomes a division by zero: undefined.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "vanishes"? Do you mean their coefficients are zero?

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú "vanishes" = "becomes zero". For instance, if the denominator is $ex+f$ for some real (and fixed) values $e,f$ with $e\neq 0$, then at the point $x=-f/e$ the denominator becomes zero.

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean that the formula for some $x$ is undefined, because of division by zero.

Example:

$$\frac{3x^2+5x+6}{x^2-2x+1}$$

If $x=1$, the denominator is 0 and the result is undefined.

---

Other possibility: When $d=e=f=0$, the formula is undefined for all $x$.

Comment: But they are talking for the formula as a whole, as it seems, and thus not for a specific case where the function is undefined.

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú I added another possibility.